# e2e testing of an Angular app that uses (customer requirement) Firefox 38

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor

My customer is using Firefox 38 and I need to conduct e2e test of and Angular application.  I am struggling understanding which version of Protractor and Selenium I should install to get Selenium to recognize the FF 38 browser.

Comment: Down voters drop your comment and suggestion so that new member would know what is the wrong in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think 4.14 of Protractor should be the max because Protractor 5 supports Selenium 3. You then should downgrade to the version of `webdriver-manager` (you can install it as a standalone module) till you reach the version that suites your customer needs